# CSS: How to fix the width of a vertical menu?

Tags: css, menu

I'm trying to make each li item exactly the same width. For example if there's a **long text ul** make the rest of **ul** s the same size OR have a limited width size so the longest **ul** can brake into two lines.

**See the left column menu in yellow. This is what I have:**
[image]

**And this is what I aim:**

[image]

**CSS**

```
#menu-esde li a {
    background-color: #FFC477;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
#secondnav li a, #menu-esde li a {
    background-color: #FFC477;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
#secondnav li a {
    border: medium none;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
```

**Website:** 
http://npmaudiovisual.com/esde/?page_id=36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your `CSS` with my **css** :-

```
#secondnav li a, #menu-esde li a {
    background-color: #FFC477;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    text-align: left;
    width: 205px;
}
```

see the attached image result is as per your requirement :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Just now add this css**

```
#secondnav ul li {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 184px;
}

    #secondnav li a, #menu-esde li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
float:right; // remove this line 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#menu-esde li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #YOUR COLOR;
    height: 42px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    width: 100%;
}
ul#menu-esde li a {
    background-color: #YOUR COLOR;
    color: #YOUR COLOR;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 42px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```